# async void, await, and exceptions - why do exceptions thrown after 'await' from the GUI thread require AsyncVoidMethodBuilder for marshaling?

Tags: exception, asynchronous, c#-5.0, async-await

In C# 5.0 In A Nutshell, pg 590, the following example is given:

```
async void ButtonClick (object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) 
{ 
   await Task.Delay(1000); 
   throw new Exception ("Will this be ignored?"); 
}
```

The book states that the Exception will not be caught because the function will imediately return to the message loop at the await line, and when the exception is thrown one second later it will not be caught by the try/catch in the message loop.

The book goes on to state that AsyncVoidMethodBuilder has to encapsulate the continuation within another function so that it can build another try/catch block and forward any caught exceptions to the synchronization context if it is present.

This confuses me because I thought that, since the Task.Delay was being called from the GUI thread, the presence of the syncronization context would cause the continuation from Task.Delay to execute on the GUI thread already.  I would have thought that it could therefore continue exeuction directly from the message loop inside a try/catch clause and still get caught without needing to be encapsulated in another function.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you missing an event handler for Dispatcher.UnhandledException?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; the exception will be re-raised directly on the UI `SynchronizationContext` and be caught by the message loop. From there it will pass to the UI application-wide handler.

What the book actually says is that the exception cannot be caught after the `async` method returns, and this is why the `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder` will re-raise the exception on the appropriate `SynchronizationContext`.

This is important because an `async void` method may "leave" its UI context, e.g., by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. But if an exception happens after that point, it must re-sync to the original `SynchronizationContext`, not necessarily the context at the point the exception is thrown.

Comment: So what is really going on is that AsynchVoidMethodBuilder does this solely in case an exception is thrown from a continuation executing on a pool thread and is actually unncessary otherwise?  Does the Task.Delay(...) awaiter not marshal continuations to the GUI thread, and is thus why the book uses it as an example?

Comment: That's correct; the `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder` provides a single, reliable behavior for all `async void` methods. The `Delay` awaitable does capture the `SynchronizationContext`, but that is not necessarily true for all awaitables.